# angular ng-repeat callback on leave-stagger of last item

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I know this *kind of* question has been asked before, but today I face a little different case.

Here is a sample code of my case:
[plnkr.co/edit/paMfJjon3aYyBDvjZxur](http://plnkr.co/edit/paMfJjon3aYyBDvjZxur?p=preview)

Suppose you have a ng-repeat with Angular **stagger animations** on each items. The length of the list is variable, so the time to complete the animation is unknown.

I tried to use a callback like `$animate.on('leave', element, …)` but it fires on each and every list items, not when the global items collections finishes to be emptied.

What could be done here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like since the animations are created using CSS using ng-class and referencing item.$last should do the trick.

Comment: Hum… I tried several ways to implement your idea but unfortunately none of them seemed to work.

But your comment gave me the idea to use the current length of the list and do a simple sum to know how long it should take to wait for all items to leave the stage…

And it goas like this: [plnkr.co/edit/5ptgujKu99FkyivIulqZ](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ptgujKu99FkyivIulqZ?p=preview)